# Как организовать мигание вспышки

Tags: android-sdk, камера, eclipse, android

Именю такой код, для включения вспышки

```
mCamera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

И такой для выключения

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
mCamera.release();
mCamera = null;
```

Как организовать мигание вспышки по нажатию ToggleButton. То есть, есть ToggleButton ON то вспышка мигает, а если OFF то останавливается.

PS. Работать с ToggleButton умею, нужет только код, запускающий мигание.

Comment: Я думаю, Вам необходимо создать новый Thread и в нём определить цикл, который будет выполнять, пока ToggleButton включена. В самом теле цикла меняйте значение переменной с FLASH_MODE_TORCH на FLASH_MODE_OFF. И ставьте небольшую паузу Thread.sleep(500). И всё, грубо говоря.

Comment: а можно немного подробней? прочитал про thread и java.util.Timer но не получается что то :(
PS. Работаю в eclipse второй день, с java тоже столкнулся только 2 дня назад.

Comment: Через пару часов выложу работающий код. Сейчас на работе - нет времени. Потерпите немного.

Comment: Заранее большое спасибо, будем ждать :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственно, вот рабочий код. Есть маленький нюанс. Если нажать на кнопку в момент, когда вспышка будет гореть, то она так и останется гореть. Кто захочет, добавит дополнительную проверку или выключение вспышки по завершению цикла. Итак, первым делом обязательно добавляем в файл манифеста строки о доступе к камере и вспышке.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="true" />
```

По условиям вопроса я добавил на слой простую ToggleButton. Её id - btn_switch . Всё, дальше можно копировать код в своё Activity и наслаждаться морганием.

```
package com.blogspot.leved_notes.blinker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ToggleButton mSwitcher;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Parameters mParams;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSwitcher = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_switch);
        mSwitcher.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        if (!checkCameraHardware())
            gameOver();

        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        checkFlash();
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        if (mCamera != null)
            mCamera.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn, boolean state) {
        if (state) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mCamera != null) {
                        while (mSwitcher.isChecked()) {
                            String mode = mParams.getFlashMode();
                            if (mode.equals(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF))
                                mode = Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH;
                            else
                                mode = Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF;

                            mParams.setFlashMode(mode);
                            mCamera.setParameters(mParams);
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(500L);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    /** Check if this device has a camera */
    private boolean checkCameraHardware() {
        boolean result = false;
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)
                && pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
            // this device has a camera and flash
            result = true;
        } else
            gameOver();

        return result;
    }

    private void gameOver() {
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public Camera getCameraInstance() {
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        Camera c = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                try {
                    c = Camera.open(i); // attempt to get a Camera instance
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    private void checkFlash() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mParams = mCamera.getParameters();
        } else
            gameOver();
    }

}
```